# Unable to find Android WebView in Google Play store

Tags: google-play-store, 5.0-lollipop, webview

A recent Chromium blog [post](http://blog.chromium.org/2015/02/beta-channel-for-android-webview.html) contains a screenshot of a Google Play store page for the "Android System WebView".

[image: play store page]

I am unable to find this page. I have tried searching the Play Store on my Nexus 7 2013 device (which *has* Lollipop on it). Interestingly, this page does not seem to [exist](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22android+system+webview%22+site%3Aplay.google.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) on the web at all:

[image: google result]

Comment: It seems so.. I checked the package name of the APK, and it should be `com.google.android.webview`, so the Play Store link should be https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview, but it doesn't exist currently.

Comment: @AndrewT. And I don’t even have it installed as an app. If I understand correctly, the WebView should exist as a separate app on Lollipop. I don’t see it on my Nexus 7 2013.

Comment: It isn't listed on the launcher. Try checking on **Settings > Apps > All > Android System WebView**. Meanwhile, after reading the blog post, I'm thinking that the Play Store is only available for beta tester first. So, for public users, you won't see it live.

Comment: @AndrewT. Ah yes, I see it. I got version 37 (the newly announced beta is version 40).

Comment: @AndrewT. Confirmed on the web (but apparently with restricted access) https://twitter.com/passcod/status/567177405182140416

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

[Android System WebView](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview)'s update is now released for public. Still, if you want to get (beta) update earlier, then continue reading:

---

As the article says,

> If you're making use of the WebView in your app, becoming a beta channel tester will give you an early start with new APIs as well as the chance to test your app before the WebView rolls out to your users.
>
> The first version offered in the beta channel will be based on Chrome 40 and you can find a full list of changes on the chromium [blog](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/12/chrome-40-beta-powerful-offline-and.html) entry.
>
> **To become a beta tester, join the [community](https://plus.google.com/communities/105434725573080290360) which will enable you to sign up for the Beta program; you'll then be able to install the beta version of the WebView via the Play Store**. If you find any bugs, please file them on the Chromium issue tracker.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

As of current, the WebView is based on Chrome 37, while the beta channel offers Chrome 40. Also, currently there is no update publicly available, hence the [Play Store link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview) displaying "Not Found". To be able to see page (and update the WebView), you have to join beta channel testing. The guide as provided on the Google+ community:

> 1. Join [WebView Beta Channel](https://plus.google.com/communities/105434725573080290360) community on Google+.
> 2. Sign up as a tester via [this link](https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.google.android.webview).
> 3. Go to the [Play Store page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview) and ensure your devices are updated with the latest version.